# File name variable in file path in C

Tags: c, variables, text-files, filepath, fopen

So I am writing a program that uses text files. I have a line of code that goes like this.

```
pfw = fopen(fileName, "w");
```

I am trying to make that program to create a txt file in this relative path

```
./TextFiles/
```

I have no idea how to implement a fileName variable in the file path.
I usually do it like this when I have static fileName and program doesn't ask me to give it a file name or where fileName is not a variable and it works.

```
pfw = fopen("./TextFiles/fileName.txt", "w");
```

Comment: How about sprintf(&buffer, "./TextFiles/%s", filename)?

Comment: @Or more likely `buffer` instead of `&buffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `#define` the relative path if configuration files are not being used

```c
#define BASE_DIR "./TextFiles/"

char* finalName = malloc (strlen(BASE_DIR) + strlen(fileName) + 1);
if (!finalName) { /* error handling */ }

sprintf (finalName, "%s%s", BASE_DIR, fileName);

FILE* pfw = fopen(finalName, "w");
/*
...
*/
// free after usage
free (finalName);
```